Dataloader error in pytorch PascalVOC dataset: RuntimeError: each element in list of batch should be of equal size
When trying to implement the yolo algortithm, one of the steps is to resize each image to (448, 448). But even with the transform applied the Dataloader throw an exception about difference of size in the dataset.
The exact error message: "RuntimeError: each element in list of batch should be of equal size"
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import v2, ToTensor

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

validation_data = datasets.voc.VOCDetection(
    root='.DATA/',
    download=False,
    image_set="val",
    transform=v2.Compose([ v2.Resize(size=(448, 448)), ToTensor() ])
)

batch_size = 64

validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_data, batch_size=batch_size)

for X, y in validation_dataloader:
    print(f"Shape of X [N, C, H, W]: {X.shape}")
    break


Does this answer your question? Why does PyTorch dataloader require each element in the batch size to be the same?

The question does not solve my problem, considering that the function getitem in the dataset always return a tuple (tensor, dict), and the tensor has always the same size.

I'm betting it's a matter of the number of channels. [mre] required. you need just two images to reproduce this, but they've gotta be the right two images.

The code presented reproduce the error. I have solved the matter, the problem was the annotations, I don't know exactly but the dictionaries was causing the error, so after implementing the paper format all works well.
